# Show bottom sheet with dropwdown options on dropdown click in flutter

Tags: flutter, dropdown, flutter-layout, bottom-sheet

I have a `DropDown` which shows various options. The current behavior displays the options as a `DropdownMenuItem`.

How can I switch the `DropdownMenuItem` to a `BottomSheet` which shows all the options within the `DropDown`?

Current code:

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
  child: Container(
    color: Color.fromRGBO(216, 216, 216, 0.33),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32, 8, 16, 8),
    child: DropdownButton<String>(
      hint: Text("TEST DROPDOWN"),
      items: <String>['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].map((String value) {

        // this crashes
        return showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (builder) {
          return Container(
            child: Text('Hello From Modal Bottom Sheet'),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
          );
        });

        // this works
        return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: new Text(value),
        );

      }).toList(),
      ...
```

EDIT: I am trying to display something similar to an iOS date selector on dropdown click.

Comment: A showModalBottomSheet is in no way related to a DropdownMenuItem. You can't just return it inside a DropdownButton. Can you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a dropdown. Now when the user clicks on the dropdown instead of showing the list with various options, I would like to show the options in a bottom sheet.

Comment: You mean like an iOS dropdown or date select?

Comment: Yes! I should have mentioned that in the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to make your own, here's a simple example made by me:

```
class ModalDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ModalDropDownState createState() => _ModalDropDownState();
}

class _ModalDropDownState extends State<ModalDropDown> {
  String _selected = '';
  List<String> _items = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Show Modal'),
            onPressed: () => showModal(context),
          ),
          Text('Selected item: $_selected')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void showModal(context){
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context){
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          height: 200,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: ListView.separated(
            itemCount: _items.length,
            separatorBuilder: (context, int) {
              return Divider();
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                child: Text(_items[index]),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _selected = _items[index];
                  });
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                }
              );
            }
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

*If instead you want the Flutter made picker for iOS, you can use the [CupertinoPicker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker-class.html)*

Comment: The issue I am facing is how to populate a modal from the dropdown (while showing the options). I am able to show a modal on button click without any issue

Comment: I've changed my answer to use a List of strings like you do in your example.

Comment: Thanks for that! I still need to figure out how to show the modal on dropdown click rather than a button click.

Comment: You can just style a button to the way you want it to look. Why does it need to be a DropdownButton if you don't want it to behave like one?

Comment: ohh geez. didn't think of that. Thank you!

Comment: Haha. Glad I could help. Good luck with your app!